# How to edit a specific word on a specific line base on user input?

Tags: python

I am working on an Flight ticket reservation system as part of my university project. Use of Modules and Global variable are **not** allowed. My project consist of flight schedule, which is saved and stored in a .txt file named schedule.txt. It is also stated that I need to code for the admin where they can freely edit the details in flight schedule. Details in flight schedule include: Booking code, Flight number, Airline, From, To and date of departure.

```
schedule = open("schedule.txt", "w")
schedule.write("\n[100] MH371, MALAYSIAN AIRLINE, KUALA LUMPUR, BEIJING , 19-12-2021, N/A"
               "\n[200] SX849, AIRASIA          , KUALA LUMPUR, BANGKOK , 05-01-2022, N/A"
               "\n[300] MH234, MALAYSIAN AIRLINE, KUALA LUMPUR, LANGKAWI, 03-02-2022, N/A"
               "\n[400] FD709, KOREA AIRLINE    , KUALA LUMPUR, SEOUL   , 29-12-2021, N/A"
               "\n[500] Z1314, CATHAY AIRLINE   , KUALA LUMPUR, TOKYO   , 21-01-2022, N/A"
               "\n[600] HY520, EMIRATES         , KUALA LUMPUR, TAIPEI  , 15-11-2021, N/A"
               "\n[700] TT879, MALINDO AIR      , KUALA LUMPUR, HAWAII  , 08-02-2022, N/A")
schedule = open("schedule.txt", "r")
print(schedule.read())
```

Initially my code was

```
with open('schedule.txt') as new_schedule:
  contents = new_schedule.read()

old_data = str(input("Data to edit: "))
new_data = str(input("New data: "))
contents = contents.replace(old_data, new_data)

with open('schedule.txt', 'w') as file:
  schedule.write(contents)
```

But obviously this code doesn't work as there are recurring data in the txt file such as "KUALA LUMPUR" I tried to implement the enumerate() function but that reads an entire line and I don't know how to just choose to replace 1 word from that line

Comment: can you show an example of desired output? I can't understand if an edit is global on all flights, and if not, where does the admin chooses the flight to edit

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you allowed the admin to specify the flight number (or the booking code), and the field they want to edit, and finally type the new value?

Comment: yes initially did something like 
if booking_code == 100:
 XXX

however there are also option where admin can add new flight schedule, so lets say if they add new code 800, i need to manually add an additional line of 

if booking_code == 800:
 XXX

im looking for a more flexible solution where i can apply for loops

Comment: You should close the file before reopening it (or use a `with` statement to `open()` it.

Comment: maybe first read all data and convert to list of rows - and every row convert to list of cells. And then it would be simpler to work with data. Using `replace` you may replace some value in wrong row or in wrong column,.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `enumerate` to read index and string lines:

```
with open("schedule.txt") as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if i == 1:
            print(line)
```

After that, split the line with `split(',')`

```
temp = line.split(',')
```

Then replace the index of the line with the new one and use

```
" , ".join(temp)
```

Finally, replace the line with the variable `temp`.